# SCSS doesn't recognize block-grid mixin

Tags: css, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use Foundations [block-grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/block_grid.html) to space a `ul`, but am getting the error from `gulp-scss-lint`:

> Message:
>       src/scss/main.scss
>   Error: no mixin named block-grid
>
> ```
>    Backtrace:
>     src/scss/main.scss:14
>     on line 14 of src/scss/main.scss
> ```
>
> > > ```
> > > @include block-grid(
> > > ```
> > >
> > > -------------^

I've included foundation in my project with bower

```
bower install foundation-sites --save
```

and including it at the top of my main.scss file with

```
@import './bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
```

I'm not getting any error about scss not finding the file, so the path is correct. Am I not including foundation in the right way?

Comment: A cursoiry glance would indicate that the `include` is not complete. ie `@include block-grid(3);`

Comment: @Paulie_D Full include `@include block-grid($per-row: 6, $spacing: 2em, $base-style: false);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@import '../../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
```

I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, but no finding the file doesn't seem to be the problem.